# How to print a presentation (ppt) file in the most economic way?

Tags: printing, presentations, libreoffice-impress

I have a presentation with several images and a dark background. So it should be very expensive printing it.
Is there a way to printing in a "toner saving mode", ie, just black/gray color font over white background.
Mostly I ask for a software configuration way. But hardware solution is welcome too.
I am using "libreoffice" in linux and my printer is a Samsung ML-3471ND (laser B/W).

**EDIT**: Something like `Edit->[print in a very economic mode]` or `Format->[automatically turn background to white and foreground to gray scale]` etc... or maybe some printer setting.

**EDIT 2**: @diogo-rocha Why deleted your answer and my (an another user's) related comments? What is the constructive idea behind that behavior? Please think first in the community convenience.

Comment: Which version of LibreOffice are you using?

Comment: @iglvzx `LibreOffice 3.4.3`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to test this to believe it.  I think I found the answer though.  The presentation in the screen shot is normally white text on a dark blue background.  When I put it to grayscale, it goes monochrome *and* inverts.

[image]

Comment: This seems to work, make some tests with presentations with a dark background and the print result is a white background.